# Is it possible to get the first element from flux without converting flux into stream?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Is it possible to get the first element from flux without converting flux into stream?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Alternatively to `take(1)`, if you need a `Mono<T>` that represents the first element of the `Flux<T>` you can use `.next()`.

Or if you need the i-th element, use `.elementAt(i)` (must be sure that such an element exists though, unlike `take` and `next` which just return an empty publisher if not enough elements).

Comment: Thanks @Simon for you reply. I idea here is to sort the Flux first and then get the first element. After seeing the docs I can achieve the same by using reduce on the flux as below. Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
   .reduce((o1, o2) -> {
                    if (o1 - o2 < 0) {
                        return o1;
                    }
                    return o2;
                })

Answer (score 4):

`Flux.range(1,10).take(1)` should do the trick (the `range(...)` part here is only to emit some sample values; if you `blockFirst()` or `subscribe()` to the stream, you should see **'1'**)

Answer (score 0):

Also the easiest: you can convert your `Flux` to `Mono` using [Mono.from()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#from-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-)

```
Mono<T> mono = Mono.from(flux);
```

It takes the first element of flux or completes with empty if flux has not emitted any element.